# Finish paper or broaden question

Tags: publications, phd, mathematics

I'm writing a paper on an extension of a topic I investigated in my PhD thesis. The paper refines what is known about a particular (automaton) model, call it A. I find the paper interesting. On the one hand, it uses classical results from a theoretical field (logic) and applies it to a practical problem. On the other hand, the solution is not completely straightforward. In fact, I came back to this problem after not having been able to solve it months ago.

Now, a researcher in my thesis committee sent me a paper discussing another model, let's call it B. It seems that B is more general than A but for that reason the properties one can prove about B are not as strong. Still there seems to be a transfer of ideas I used in my thesis in the study of B. The paper contains a number of "open problems". It also provides motivating material to continue developing my paper on model A.

I'm working alone on this problem and preparing simultaneously a grant application finishing in two months.

**Question**

Should I stop writing my paper on A and understand the unclear points in B? Should I keep writing my paper on A borrowing ideas from the development in B and stating that they motivated the questions I ask about A? In the latter case, should I defer the publication of A until I try the problems in B to avoid not solving the problems in B with the new techniques I come up for A?

I can work on a paper and a grant writing simultaneously but more would be difficult. Ideally, I should have the support of master students or my PhD advisor. But he left me on my own for the whole degree.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without knowing your career position and your career ambitions.  Answers are going to be very different if you're in a teaching-oriented position which doesn't expect more research than for you to publish one mediocre paper before tenure or if you're a postdoc planning to leave mathematics for an unrelated industry job if you can't get a position at Berkeley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your advisor would be the best person to advice you on this.

But also their answer should be filtered considering your own schedule and ambitions. I assume that if you extend the paper you could probably target a higher IF journal than with the current status, but you will need more time for that.